# WP_Query displaying ALL posts

Tags: wp-query, post-meta

I cannot figure out why my `WP_Query` always displays all my published posts regardless of what I put in the arguments.

```
<?php 

    $args = array('numberposts' => 1,
                    'meta_key' => 'display',
                    'meta_value' => 'about'
    );

    $about_preview_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($about_preview_query->have_posts()) {
        print "<h1>FOUND POSTS</h1>";
    }

    while ($about_preview_query->have_posts()) {
        $about_preview_query->the_post();
        print "<h1>";
        the_title();

        print "</h1>";

    }
?>
```

Am I doing something wrong here? After readings the docs on `WP_Query()` I cannot figure out where I'm going wrong, appreciate any help I can get.

**Update**

I've tried this code and I am still getting the same response. All the posts are being returned in the loop.

```
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'display',
                'value' => 'about',
                'compare' => '=',
             )
        ),
    );
```

Update 2

It seems if I print `$about_preview_query->found_posts` the output is 1. So I suspect there is something wrong with how I am looping the posts:

```
<?php if ($about_preview_query->have_posts()): ?>

    <h1>Has <?php print $about_preview_query->found_posts ?> Posts</h1>

    <?php while ($about_preview_query->have_posts()): $about_preview_query->the_post(); ?>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried resetting your postdata?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I literally just tried putting wp_reset_postdata(); above my query a second before your comment. Still I get the same issue where it's outputting all the posts.

Comment: Below your query, do a var_dump inside a pre tag and see what is returned by your query. Example `?><pre><?php var_dump($about_preview_query); ?></pre><?php`

Comment: Strange, even though the found_posts count is 1, the var dump suggests the query is returning all posts :S.

Comment: Then there are posts injected from somewhere else. Somewhere you are running custom queries that has not being resetted. It might even be from an instance of `pre_get_posts`

Comment: I have been thinking, just as a check, remove your `meta_query` and just leave your `posts_per_page` parameter and test and see if it returns the same behavior. Also check for custom filters or functions that might inject posts into the array returned with your post

Answer (score 3):

It is because you are giving wrong arguments. Provide right arguments to [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query).

Also have a look at the [custom field parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

One more thing, you will have to use code like

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'display',
            'value'   => 'about',
            'compare' => '=', // (Read all comparison operators at provided link)
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no parameter for `numberposts`. Use `posts_per_page` instead. So your code will become...

```
<?php 

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'meta_key' => 'display',
        'meta_value' => 'about'
    );

    $about_preview_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ( $about_preview_query->have_posts() ) {
        print "<h1>FOUND POSTS</h1>";
    }

    while ( $about_preview_query->have_posts() ) {
        $about_preview_query->the_post();
        print "<h1>";
        the_title();
        print "</h1>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is change

```
'posts_per_page' => 1,
```

to

```
'posts_per_page' => -1,
```

Comment: `-1` would return all posts.